# angular 6:Nebular theme,changing layout and urls

Tags: angular6, nebular

I am new on angular and nebular. 
I am developing an app with nebular theme.

I want to know how to disable the menu on left from some pages.
(like home page)
now all pages excepting login and register shows the menu on left 
and how to disable the # from the url for all the links (login and pages)
removing

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

from app.module make a problem with login and register links on the server

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Removing Hash # from URL:**
Go to your `app-routing-module.ts` and change `true` to `false`:

```
const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: false,
};
```

And you need to set base URL in the index.html:

```
<base href="/">
```

**Hide the theme menu:**
Locate this file in your project: https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/tree/master/src/app/%40theme/components/header

And remove:

```
<nb-action icon="nb-gear" class="toggle-layout" (click)="toggleSettings()"></nb-action>
```

Note: It depends how you are using the Nebular. You might have this file in `node_modules` but I have it under my `app` folder because I copied the whole framework and customized it.

Comment: Hi Maihan, thank you for your answer, Removing Hash is working in local but in server, with login url I got the error : 'can/t get auth/login'. For the menu, I am talking about the Left Menu(nb-menu) not the right Menu: I want to show it in pages and hide it from other pages.